# Can´t access the UI of Jena Fuseki on Ubuntu 16 (Google Cloud Compute Engine)

Tags: google-compute-engine, jena, fuseki, ubuntu-16.04

I´m trying to run Jena Fuseki on Ubuntu 16 (Google Cloud Compute Engine).

The steps I did so far are:

1. Downloaded apache-jena-fuseki-2.4.0 and extracted it in the folder /opt
2. Executed the command "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jena-fuseki-2.4.0" and "export FUSEKI_HOME=/opt/jena-fuseki-2.4.0"
3. Created the folder dataDir in /opt/jena-fuseki-2.4.0
4. Started Jena: "fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataset"

After that fuseki is running successfully but i can´t access the UI when I open the URL: http://myIP:3030

The HTTP and HTTPS Traffic is enabled in the Google Cloud Compute configuration and openjdk 8 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Do check the server log in case there is something there.

Security is controlled by the "shiro.ini" file.

The default behaviour is to limit the UI admin functions to "localhost". The admin UI wil appear but be non-functional.

You'll need to change the security (notes are in that file) to allow remote UI admin functions.

But if you mean you can't access the front page at all, something else is going on that is outside the Fuseki server.  In which case, try an HTTP query request to `http://myIP:3030/myDataset/query` and check the server log file.

Comment: Yes, I can´t see the UI when I try to open http://myIP:3030. But when i do a HTTP query request the server response with a 200 message. So Jena seems to run successfully and that means it is a ubuntu or google cloud configuration issue ;(. I also have Jetty running at the port 8080 and have no problems to access the jetty UI or the UI of my webapp

Comment: Try wegt/curl to http://myIP:3030/ and see if anything comes back.  Do you get 200 or 404 to that?  Then check the content assets (CSS, JS) are available.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to my Console.

2) Choose you Project.

3) Choose "Compute Engine" instance.

4) Click "Networks" (It will say default).

5) Choose the interface for you Instances.

6) In firewall rule create a new rule with "Protocols & Ports"-"tcp:3030".

I hope this help you.